# RAM on Lenovo G50 laptop

Tags: ram

So my Lenovo G50 is running as standard with 4 GB RAM. I have got the idea to make an upgrade and when I have Ubuntu on the Lenovo G50 I was thinking this was the right place.

How many RAM does Ubuntu supports?

I have found this:

https://www.komplett.dk/product/752033/pc-tablets/pc-tilbehoer/hukommelse-ram/crucial-ddr3l-1600mhz-8gb-sodimm#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 64bit is not the bottleneck when installing RAM on a laptop. It will support as much ram as you will give it.

Whether the linked memory is compatible with your Lenovo G50 is off topic on askubuntu (and I do not know the answer to it).

Comment: Regarding the off-topic problem... Maybe the OP should go to https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ to seek further help.

Comment: So what you say is if my Lenovo G50 support 16 GB ram there will not be a problem to plug 16GB ram in it. My questinen was made because I have read on another side where they told me that Ubuntu was not happy for too many Ram. So I just wanted to now how meny Rams it was

Comment: @JimmiLarsen I use Ubuntu with 32GB ram and I dont know if it is happy, but I sure am ;-)

Comment: Oaky thanks for answar I got my information I need I will mark this post as solved

Answer (score 0):

Basically It depends on your machine. If your motherboard supports 8 GB RAM, Ubuntu will support it. The maximum amount is depend on your notebook.

Google as "(**Exact** computer model) ram support" and find your "**exact**" RAM option.

Be careful to look DDR type and RAM speed that your machine needs. If your notebook supports 1066 MHz and you buy 1600 MHz, it will run it on 1066 MHz. However if you buy DDR2 RAM and your notebook supports DDR3, you cannot plug the new RAM to the notebook.

Ask more about hardware specs in [here](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).